# Use Artifactory Rest API to get most recent (non-maven) file

Tags: rest, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to use the Artifactory Rest API to retrieve the latest published version of a file. The file in question is a simple zip of a bunch of YAML files used for configuration. I can upload and download these files in TeamCity using [File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs), however I can't find any reference of this functionality in the Rest API docs (or indeed, any way to do almost anything that isn't an action on a maven repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and use a custom [Repository Layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts). This way, in order to download the latest version of the file, you can use the `[RELEASE]` placeholder. The actual latest version will be automatically resolved by the extracted version value based on the layout.

See also:

- [How to create simple versioning custom layout in Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-simple-versioning-custom-layout-in-artifactory/)
- [How to find the latest artifact version based on layout?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-find-the-latest-artifact-version-based-on-layout/)

Answer (score 2):

As you are already using the file specs, you can make use of the same file spec and use the [Artifactory query language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language) (AQL) to get the list of files. You can refer to [example 2](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-Examples) here in this list.