# How to upload artifacts to Artifactory with timestamps in their name and then download the latest version?

Tags: devops, artifactory

I want to be able to upload artifacts to Artifactory with timestamps in their name as a form of revision. As an example, the artifact could be named "artifact-1.1.0-20230522122630.zip" where the "1.1.0" is the base revision and the "20230522122630" is the file revision. I have created the following layout to support this:

[Artifactory Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/811xM.png)

Now, I would like to download the latest version of that artifact but for that I first need to know which artifact is the latest. From the REST API I found this: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/artifact-latest-version-search-based-on-layout

Which should make me able to get both base- and file-revision of my artifact, however, when I perform the following request:

http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/search/latestVersion?g=path.DEVELOP&a=artifact&v=*

I get this: "1.1.0-"

The file revision is for some reason left out... I expected this: "1.1.0-20230522122630"

Appreciates any help that you could provide me with.

Answer (score 0):

After you define the custom [Repository Layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts), in order to download the latest version of the file, you can use the `[RELEASE]` placeholder. The actual latest version will be automatically resolved by the extracted version value based on the layout.

See also: [How to create simple versioning custom layout in Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-simple-versioning-custom-layout-in-artifactory/)

(based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046423/3211710) to a similar question)